# How to build eTags for a source tree on a remote host "Tramp"

Tags: emacs, elisp, tramp, etags

I am using TRAMP to connect remotely to the servers where the source tree is.
I havent figured a way to build eTags for the tree "relative" to the remote server.
Meaning, the server might look like:
/ssh:server1:/home/user/tree

Looking up eTags from inside emacs looks for the directory:
/home/user/tree instead.

Any pointers how this could be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, a while back; I haven't gotten around to putting together a fully general solution, but you may find some value in [the Perl script I hacked up to do the job](http://web.archive.org/web/20140410190051/http://blog.aaron-miller.me/etags-via-ssh-for-remotely-hosted-codebases-a-first-draft/), which served my admittedly simple purpose at the time.

Comment: The Perl script pointed out in the answer is not available anymore, does anybody have a copy?. Thanks

Comment: @FelipeReyes My blog's kind of dead at the moment, so I pointed the link in this comment to an Internet Archive scrape of it. The script's inlined into the post body, so you should be able to grab it without too much trouble.